# Selection of specific outputs with a string column

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a report on a hotel and I need to sum up some informartion about the board they booked.

Right now my output looks like this:

```
SELECT meal.id, meal.title,
    SUM(CASE WHEN meal.id >= 600 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) as NoofMeals
    FROM meal
    JOIN itinerary i ON i.id = meal.journeyid
    WHERE i.arrival BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-01'
    GROUP BY meal.title
```

My Output looks like this:

```
ID    | title                  | NoofMeals

608   | Dinner                 | 15
621   | Breakfast              | 478
648   | Lunch                  | 74
649   | Breakfast Box          | 5
655   | Lunch-Box              | 7
659   | American breakfast     | 73
671   | Continental breakfast  | 102
674   | All Inclusive          | 312
689   | All Inclusive from 3pm | 7
693   | Picnic                 | 47
```

My desired Ouput would look like this and put together different values, like all the breakfast things (Breakfast, Breakfast Box, American Breakfast and Continental Breakfast) or all the All Inclusives (All Inclusive and All Inclusive from 3pm). Unfortunately the IDs are not sequential.

```
title                  | NoofMeals

Dinner                 | 15
Breakfast              | 658
Lunch                  | 81
All Inclusive          | 319
Picnic                 | 7
```

I don't need the IDs anymore, I just need to be able to rename the title of meal.

I hope you can help me, please take it easy on me, I'm pretty new to MySQL.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your table's data

Comment: Is Picnic 7 or 47 in desired output?

Comment: It's supposed to be 47, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "quick and dirty" solution would make use of string functions:

```
SELECT
  case
    when meal.title like '%Breakfast%' then 'Breakfast'
    when meal.title like '%All inclusive%' then 'All Inclusive'
    else meal.title
  end as title,
  ...
...
GROUP BY
  case
    when meal.title like '%Breakfast%' then 'Breakfast'
    when meal.title like '%All inclusive%' then 'All Inclusive'
    else meal.title
  end
```

while a proper solution is to add a column that contains the meal category:

```
id | title                  | category
---|------------------------|--------------
1  | Breakfast              | Breakfast
2  | American breakfast     | Breakfast
3  | Continental breakfast  | Breakfast
4  | All Inclusive          | All Inclusive
5  | All Inclusive from 3pm | All Inclusive
```

and join the specific meal and group by `meal.category` instead of `meal.title`.

Comment: Thanks a million, it works great!! I guess I sat there too long and missed the forest for the trees! Thank you :)